# Unit testing Symfony 2 form with event subscriber

Tags: php, phpunit, symfony-2.1

Based on the tutorial here:
[How to Dynamically Generate Forms Using Form Events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_generation.html)

I have created a form that uses an event subscriber:

```
class PageType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', 'text');

        $blockSubscriber = new AddBlocksSubscriber($builder->getFormFactory());
        $builder->addEventSubscriber($blockSubscriber);
    }

    // ...
}
```

So far so good... until I decide to write some unit tests. ;) The use of the 'new' keyword is problematic because it prevents me from using a mock subscriber object.

I can think of two possible solutions:

1. Use test helpers/class posing, as described [here](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-test-helpers#class-posing):
   Seems a bit cumbersome though and requires a PHP extension. It doesn't 'feel' right having to do this, but might be a practical work-around.
2. Use dependency injection, e.g. make the PageType form constructor require an instance of a block subscriber. 
   The problem I'm finding here is that to create a subscriber object outside of the form, I'll also need an instance of the form builder. As the form is usually built by calling `createForm()` in the controller, I won't usually have visibility of the builder from outside of the form.

Alternatively, is it really necessary to unit test forms, or is a functional test of the final output using the crawler sufficient?

For anyone who's implemented a few Symfony2 forms, I'd be interested to know how you approached it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Symfony2 cookbook now contains a chapter dedicated to forms unit testing:
http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/unit_testing.html